# Significant Difference in Loading Time Between Original URL and Redirect

Tags: dns, cloudflare, web-hosting, namecheap

I'm new to web development and have encountered an issue with the loading times of my web app, which I'm hoping to get some help with.

**Background:**
I developed a web app accessible at `https://solo-fsw.shinyapps.io/lavaangui/`. I wanted a simpler URL, so I purchased `http://lavaangui.org/` from Namecheap and pointed this to `https://solo-fsw.shinyapps.io/lavaangui/`.

**Issue:**
I've noticed a significant difference in loading times between the two URLs:

- The original URL (`https://solo-fsw.shinyapps.io/lavaangui/`) loads in about 1 second.
- The new URL (`http://lavaangui.org/`) takes approximately 5 seconds to load, with a lot of variance. Sometimes it loads much faster and sometimes it takes > 10 seconds.

**Attempts to Resolve:**
Initially, I thought the issue might be with Namecheap's DNS servers, so I switched the nameservers to Cloudflare. However, the problem persists even after this change.

Any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Tags:** `web-hosting`, `dns`, `performance`, `cloudflare`, `namecheap`

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without knowledge of internal, but looks like your address `https://solo-fsw.shinyapps.io/lavaangui/` pointing to some IP addresses, and you create a new one DNS record `http://lavaangui.org/` and pointing to the same Ip addresses, I'm right?

if so, I think the issue can be in some internal logic, which check your HTTP header, in that case you can override it via Cloudflare "Transform Rules" option, how described here https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/request-header-modification/create-dashboard/

Also, as a second option you can try to create a CNAME record with Name `lavaangui.org` and Target `solo-fsw.shinyapps.io`, maybe it will be sutable for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with DNS, name lookup, or redirects. The Shinyapps service varies in response time by a large amount. My guess is the startup (cold start) time varies by a large amount.

I used the CLI tool `curl` to test both URLs. First I created a file to display various times including DNS name lookup:

curl-format.txt:

```
     time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}s\n
        time_connect:  %{time_connect}s\n
     time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}s\n
    time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}s\n
       time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}s\n
  time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}s\n
          time_total:  %{time_total}s\n
```

I used this command to test the first URL:

```
curl -w @curl-format.txt -s -o output.html https://solo-fsw.shinyapps.io/lavaangui/
```

I ran the command twice. Notice the variation in time:

```
      time_namelookup:  0.087324s
         time_connect:  0.194781s
      time_appconnect:  0.414386s
     time_pretransfer:  0.414526s
        time_redirect:  0.000000s
   time_starttransfer:  4.321403s
           time_total:  4.323718s

      time_namelookup:  0.005384s
         time_connect:  0.084560s
      time_appconnect:  0.246017s
     time_pretransfer:  0.246136s
        time_redirect:  0.000000s
   time_starttransfer:  0.340210s
           time_total:  0.340989s
```

Then I tested the second URL:

```
curl -w @curl-format.txt -s -o output.html http://lavaangui.org/
```

The variation this time is not so severe:

```
     time_namelookup:  0.123519s
        time_connect:  0.187978s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.188123s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.250556s
          time_total:  0.250624s

     time_namelookup:  0.005591s
        time_connect:  0.064566s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.064699s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.135981s
          time_total:  0.136040s
```

There is about a 100ms difference in DNS name resolution, but that is normal. The `time_starttransfer` is the issue and that is your cold start time. Curl has connected to the service and is waiting for the first by of data.